# Regular expression for finding special character between double quotes

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed

i have a csv file with the below format..

```
001,"Craig,betsy",Newyork
002,"sam.nathan",charlotte
```

i need to find the comma inside double quotes in the file.. kindly help me in getting the regular expression in unix or perl..

or else to avoid the comma inside double quotes..

i need the output file to be like this

001|"Craig,betsy"|Newyork

002|"sam.nathan"|charlotte.

please help with the inputs added..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do once you find the comma inside quotes?

Comment: What do you mean find? Find for what? `sed -r -n '/".*,.*"/p'` will print the lines have comma inside a double quotes.

Comment: You probably want to use a [CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

Answer (score 1):

**Perl One-Liner**

With your input, you can use this:

```
perl -ne 'while(m/"[^",]+\K,(?=[^",]*")/g){print "$&\n";}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that will change the filed separator to `|`

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {c+=gsub(/\"/,"&",$i);printf "%s"(c%2?FS:"|"),$i}print $NF}' t
001|"Craig,betsy"|Newyork
002|"sam.nathan"|charlotte
```

It divides data into group separated by `,`.  Then it count how many `"` it finds in every field.
When number can be divide by two then use `|`, if not use `,`

---

If you have `gnu awk 4.xxx` you can use `FPAT`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s|",$i;print $NF}' FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' t
001|"Craig,betsy"|Newyork
002|"sam.nathan"|charlotte
```

How does this `FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"'` work?
It define who a field looks like, not what is separator.
`[^,]+` a field is some that does not contain `,` or
`"[^"]+"` some start with `"` then characters not equal `"` and ends with  `"`.  Eks `"my,data"` or `"data"`